# Dynamically injected java script is not working in Ektron widget

Tags: ektron

I have injected html div contains button and javascript into an Ektron widget on button click.But when I click the injeted button, javascript function is not called.If I inject script in the Page_Load of Ektron widget the java script function is calling perfectly.

Please check this.

Default.ascx.cs

```
 public partial class Workarea_Widgets_test : WorkareaWidgetBaseControl, IWidget
      {
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {

          }
         protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
            HtmlDiv.InnerHtml = "<div id='divid'>Name :<input  type='button'  
            id='Name' name='Name' value='Injected Button' onclick='return   test();'/> 
            </div><script type='text/javascript' >function test()
            {alert('test  passed!');} </script>"; 

            HtmlDiv.Style.Add("display", "block");
           }
      }
```

Default.ascx

```
    <div id="Div1"  runat="server" class="HtmlDiv" style="display:block" >
      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click"  />
    </div>
    <div id="HtmlDiv" runat="server">
    </div>
```

If I Inject the html along with javascript in the page load of widget the javascript function is working.If it is in a button click it's not working.

I tried this code with an aspx page and it is working fine ....

Is  there any dependencies exists for Ektron Widget.

Anyone please reply.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you wouldn't just do all of this client side (JavaScript)?

To answer your question, however, an Ektron widget is just an ASP.NET web user control.  You have to manage state for web user controls, meaning when you set your HtmlDiv control's properties on post back, you are responsible for retaining those values.

See Microsoft's [ASP.NET State Management Recommendations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more information, however your options for state include:

- View state
- Control state
- Hidden fields
- Cookies
- Query strings

In this case View State or Control State would be the most likely candidates for you.

Again, though, I would question why you need to do this server side.

Comment: Agree with your first sentence. Generally speaking, writing HTML or JavaScript for output from code-behind is a practice best avoided.